# jquery autocomplete from custom source + angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am new to angular.js and jquery. Was trying to implement autocomplete from custom source consisting of an array of objects having names and emails. User will enter name and will be shown matching names in the autocomplete dropdown. When user selects one name the corresponding email will be filled in the autocomplete box.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
<body ng-controller='FriendController'>
<form ng-submit="addFriend()">
    <input type="email" auto-complete ui-items="fbFriends" ng-model="friend" autofocus />
</form>

<ul ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    <li>
        {{friend.text}}
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var addFriendAppModule = angular.module('addFriendApp', []);
    addFriendAppModule.controller('FriendController',
    function($scope) {

        var friendArr = [];

        $scope.fbFriends = [
            {
            name: "manu", 
            email: "sept@gmail.com"
            },
            {
            name: "manu123", 
            email: "sept123@gmail.com"
            }
        ];
        $scope.friends = friendArr;         
        $scope.friend = '';

        $scope.addFriend = function() {
            var newFriend = $scope.friend.trim();
            if (newFriend.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            friendArr.push(
                {text: newFriend}
            );
        };      
    });

    addFriendAppModule.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
        return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                focus: function(event,ui) {
                    iElement.val(ui.item.email);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                        iElement.val(ui.item.email);
                        return false;
                      //  iElement.trigger('input');
                       // iElement.trigger('submit');
                }
            }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ui, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .append(item.email)
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    });



</script>
```

Comment: did you check out the angularjs ui typeahead? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#typeahead

Comment: nup will try that now... thanks... meanwhile do you see the problem in my snippet?

Comment: hey got it to work.. needed to replace name with value in the array of objects and in _renderItem the function params were supposed to be ul,item and not ui,item....

Comment: but now there are more problems.. when I try to use the arrow keys to scroll through the list I get more errors...

Answer (score 0):

needed to replace name with value in the array of objects and in _renderItem the function params were supposed to be ul,item and not ui,item....

```
<body ng-controller='FriendController'>
<form ng-submit="addFriend()">
    <input type="email" auto-complete ui-items="fbFriends" ng-model="friend" autofocus />
</form>

<ul ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    <li>
        {{friend.text}}
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var addFriendAppModule = angular.module('addFriendApp', []);
    addFriendAppModule.controller('FriendController',
    function($scope) {

        var friendArr = [];

        $scope.fbFriends = [
            {
            value: "manu", 
            email: "sept@gmail.com"
            },
            {
            value: "manu123", 
            email: "sept123@gmail.com"
            }
        ];
        $scope.friends = friendArr;         
        $scope.friend = '';

        $scope.addFriend = function() {
            var newFriend = $scope.friend.trim();
            if (newFriend.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            friendArr.push(
                {text: newFriend}
            );
        };      
    });

    addFriendAppModule.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
        return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                focus: function(event,ui) {
                    iElement.val(ui.item.email);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                        iElement.val(ui.item.email);
                        return false;
                      //  iElement.trigger('input');
                       // iElement.trigger('submit');
                }
            }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append(item.email)
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    });



</script>
```

Comment: There are more problems now... in the dropdown when I try to use the arrow keys to scroll and select an entry I get the following errors... SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I was able to make application.
In your autoComplete directive under the _renderItem section, make the following changes:

```
//Change this:
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append(item.email)
                .appendTo(ul);
        };

//to:
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .attr( "data-value", item.email )
                .append( $( "<a>" ).text(item.email))
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Notice the change from autocomplete to ui-autocomplete, and the .append section wrapping the

items in a href.  I was following your example above, and that's how I got it to work for me.